# In each case, write down a sentence of $L_i$ which is true in $A_i$ but not in $B_i$ . Explain your answers briefly.

Tags: logic

$L_1$ has a single binary relation symbol $R$ . The domain of $A_1$ is $\mathbb N$ and $R(x_1, x_2)$ is interpreted as $x_1 \le x_2$. The domain of $B_1$ is $\mathbb Z$ and $R(x_1,x_2)$ is interpreted as $x_1 \le x_2$.

and

$L_4$ has a single binary relation symbol $R$. The domain of $A_4$ is $\mathbb N$ and $R(x_1, x_2)$ is interpreted as ‘$x_1, x_2$ are congruent modulo 3’. The domain of $B_4$ is $\mathbb N$ and $R(x_1, x_2)$ is interpreted as ‘$x_1, x_2$ are congruent modulo 5’.

I really have no idea how to go about this, especially due to the less than or equal to inequalities.

thanks

Comment: For $L_1$ try with the sentence : $\exists x_1 \forall x_2 R(x_1,x_2)$; "translate" it into words and check it in the interpretation $A_1$ with domain $\mathbb N$ and in the interpretation $B_1$ with domain $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: About the other part of the question (the simpler one) I would try with the sentence $R(9,3)$ ...

Answer (score 0):

I will do a related problem that shows how to think about it.  Let $R(x_1,x_2)$ be interpreted as $ x_1 \lt x2$.  The idea is to find a sentence that is true in $\Bbb N$ and not true in $\Bbb Z$.  The intuitive difference is that $\Bbb N$ has a bottom and $\Bbb Z$ does not, so we can use $\exists x (\lnot \exists y R(y,x))$, which says there is an element ($0$ in $\Bbb N$, none in $\Bbb Z$) for which there is nothing less.

Comment: I have seen this in lectures,  but cannot understand how to get the question i have been given to work with the less than or equal to inequality

Comment: $0$ is less than or equal to everything...  Mauro ALLEGRANZA gave you a sentence.

Comment: we can't see how to move from the example you have given to the question i am given

Comment: Do you see Mauro ALLEGRANZA's answer?  That applies directly.  Instead of nothing less he uses everything is greater

Comment: I can only see your answer

Comment: He gave it as a comment to the question.  Maybe click on the title to your question to refresh the screen.

Comment: how does that say that everything is greater?

Comment: It says there is an element ($x_1$) such that for all elements ($x_2$) we have $x_1 \le x_2$.  Isn't that true if $x_1=0$?

Comment: yes but isn't that then true in the naturals and the rationals?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13156/discussion-between-ross-millikan-and-zzs14)

Comment: By the way, Z is the integers.  No, it is not true in the integers (or rationals).  Whatever $x_1$ you choose, I can find a smaller $x_2$.  In the naturals, if you choose $x_1=0$ I can't find a smaller $x_2$